# How to consume web API with authentication in Excel 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, excel-2010

I have an exmaple of mvc 4 web API , and I want to consume it in Excel 2010. whats the easiest way to do it? I am thinking to pass in the username and password as string parameter if solution need to be complicated.

```
        [Authorize]
        public class AccountBalanceApiController : ApiController
        {
            //http://localhost/FTAccounting/api/AccountBalanceApi?companyId=16&fiscalYear=2012
            public Dictionary<int, TrialBalanceAccountSummaryModel> Get(int companyId, int fiscalYear)
            {
                return AccountBalance.GetTrialBalance(companyId, fiscalYear);
            }
        }
```

Update: Web service Authentication is not possible in Excel. Reference from  http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/using-the-webservice-function-in-excel-2013/

Answer (score 2):

web service Authentication is not possible in Excel. reference from http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/using-the-webservice-function-in-excel-2013/

Comment: Please don't give up.  You need to write some VBA to create XmlHttp request objects.  In addition a layer of encryption needs to be added.  I'm still looking for the answer.

Comment: @SMeaden were you able to find anything regarding this?

Comment: @kamalpreet  This guy has some libraries though I have not used them, https://timhall.github.io/ https://twitter.com/timhalldesign

Comment: @tim-hall , can you assist?

Answer (score 0):

In modern Excel you can use **Get & Transform** to connect to Web API with authorisation. Select *Data* tab, then in the *Get & Transform* group *New Query* -> *From Other Sources* -> *From Web* (Note: do not confuse this with '*From Web*' button which is directly in the *Get External Data* group). Enter your endpoint URL (you can also define request headers here) and in the next step you will be asked for authentication method.

[image: Access Web content]