# Consuming a secure ASP.Net WebAPI from Excel

Tags: excel, asp.net-web-api, vba

Is it possible to consume a WebAPI that needs authentication from Excel? 
For a regular .Net clients, we send the authentication credentials to the Token endpoint of WebAPI and get the token which is then attached as bearer in subsequent calls. 
But how is this done from Excel? What objects needs to be used in the VBA code behind?

The WebAPI is returning a collection of objects which needs to displayed in Excel as columns and rows.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to consume web API with authentication in Excel 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18119393/456814).

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember XHR, or should I say XML HTTP Request :) ?

Here is an example that I've written on a project of mine, to authenticate a user calling a web service returning data from an Oracle database:

```
Dim xhr As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest")
    Application.StatusBar = "Error 0, has occured while creating a MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest object"
End If

If xhr Is Nothing Then
    Application.StatusBar = "For some reason it wasn't possible to make a MSXML2.XMLHTTP object"
    Exit Function
End If

'consuming the web service.
xhr.Open "POST", "/webservice/url/goes/here", False
xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xhr.send "post parameters can be sent here format: paramname=paramvalue&paramname2=paramvalue2"

If xhr.Status = 200 Then    
    'creating the XmlDocument to load the received data.
    Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set xDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    xDoc.setProperty "ProhibitDTD", False
    xDoc.setProperty "ResolveExternals", True

    'loading the data into the in-memory xml document.
    xDoc.validateOnParse = True
    xDoc.async = False
    xDoc.LoadXML xhr.responseText
    Application.StatusBar = False

    'xDoc now holds your web service returned data
End If
```

The above code can be used to connect to a web service.
In this link http://www.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/snippets/basicauth there is further detail on how to achieve Basic Authentication.

Hope this helps you along the way,

Regards.